# SQL Count(Select) Query

Tags: mysql, select, join, count

I am working on a sql query to do the following:

For each project, retrieve the project number, the project name, the number  of employees who work on that project.

Here is what I have so far:

```
select pno, pname, 
    count(select fname from

    employee inner join works_on
    on employee.ssn=works_on.essn 

    inner join project 
    on works_on.pno=project.pno)

as  num_emp from project
```

Which gives me this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select fname from employee inner join works_on on employee.ssn=works_on.essn inn' at line 1

Which I am assuming means I can't put a select statement inside a count function, but I do not see how else to do this

Attached is my schema

[image: ER Diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it like this, grouping on the project details for which you want the employee count:

```
SELECT
    pno,
    pname,
    COUNT(employee.snn) AS num_emp
FROM
    project
INNER JOIN
    works_on
    ON works_on.pno = project.pno
INNER JOIN
    employee
    ON employee.ssn = works_on.essn
GROUP BY
    pno,
    pname;
```

**EDIT:**

Actually, if you want to list projects with no employees assigned then you could make your original query more correct by doing something like:

```
SELECT
    pno,
    pname,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(fname)
        FROM
            employee
        INNER JOIN
            works_on
            ON employee.ssn = works_on.essn 
        WHERE
            works_on.pno = project.pno
    ) AS num_emp
FROM
    project;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the sub query

Count(employee ID) and group by the other fields

Answer (score 0):

Use a `COUNT(*)` with an ordinary join and `GROUP BY`.

```
select p.pno, p.pname, COUNT(*) AS num_emp
FROM project AS p
JOIN works_on AS w ON w.pno = p.pno
GROUP BY p.pno
```

You don't need to join the `employee` table because you're not using any information from that table -- the information is all in `works_on`.

If you need to include projects with no employees working on them, you need to use a left join.

```
select p.pno, p.pname, COUNT(w.pno) AS num_emp
FROM project AS p
LEFT JOIN works_on AS w ON w.pno = p.pno
GROUP BY p.pno
```

In the unlikely case that there can be multiple entries in `works_on` for the same project+employee, use `COUNT(DISTINCT w.essn)` in the queries so they're not counted multiple times.

Comment: Could cause an issue, if the same employee has multiple entries, they get counted twice.

Comment: @VikingBlooded Why would you enter the same employee multiple times in  for a project? In any rational design, `pno, essn` would be a unique key in the `works_on` table.

Comment: works_on is a join, it is entirely possible and probable that an employee may be entered multiple times with different hours. In a real world environment, it's entirely possible.

Comment: I'm guessing `hours` is the total hours, not a schedule, so there would only be one entry. Unfortunately, the diagram doesn't show the keys.

Comment: Yeah, that was my initial thought too, but, in the wild, who the hell knows what they might end up doing.

Comment: OK, I've added to the answer showing how to work around that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT pno, pname,count(fname) AS Cnt
FROM employee, works_on, project 
WHERE employee.ssn=works_on.essn 
  AND works_on.pno=project.pno
GROUP BY pno,pname
```